# How to display data from one single column into multiple inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I work on an application and I have a model with a 'movies' attribute (top 5 movies). When a user tries to edit the top 5 movies I want to display each movie in a different input, but I don't know how to do it (because all 5 movies represent one single attribute)

In my controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.movies = @user.movies.split(',')
end
```

In my view

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :movies %>
  <%= f.text_field :movies[0] %>
  .
  .
  .
  <%= f.label :movies %>
  <%= f.text_field :movies[4] %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, this doesn't work!

Comment: Can you show us the model part, to understand how you defined your ``movies`` attribute? Is it a text field, or is it an association to another model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add use a virtual attribute in your `User` model to handle this, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def movies_list
    movies.split(',')
  end

  def movies_list=(list)
    self.movies = list.join(',')
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you just do:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And in your view you can handle your form like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :movies %>

  <%- @user.movies_list.each do |movie| %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'user[movies_list][]'  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That will allow your `update` action on the `users_controller` to access the movies array in `params[:user][:movies_list]`, that the model will understand and process.

At last, don't forget to add `:movies_list` to your permitted params on the controller if you need to.

*EDIT*: Thanks to @BroiSatse in the comments, as an alternative to the `text_field_tag` syntax you can use form-builder's `f.text_field :movies_list, multiple: true, value: movie`

Comment: instead of `text_field_tag 'user[movies_list][]'` you can use form_builder: `f.text_field :movies_list, multiple: true, value: movie`